# SQL script to return available agents ID doesn't work, why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would much appreciate it if you can help me to find the problem with my SQL script or provide me with alternative. I have contact center database and I'm trying to write a SQL script that will return the ID of the agents who were available when the call was received.

The script I have is working most of the time, but recently I found it doesn't work in some cases when I checked the table. One of the calls was received and by checking the table which has records for calls answered by agents, I see that there were 2 agents available, but the script doesn't return the ID of these 2 agents.

The call was received at 11:26:13 and the caller waited for approximately 2 minutes and half then he dropped the call at 11:28:42
at that time I see that agents with ID 1019 and 1033 were available but my SQL script for some reason doesn't work for this case.

```
SessionID  SessionSeqNum  ResourceID  RingTime  TalkTime  HoldTime  CSQID  StartDateTime        EndDateTime
100028     0              1028        3         334       0         5      2022-03-05 11:04:35  2022-03-05 11:10:12
100029     0              1019        13        500       0         5      2022-03-05 11:05:12  2022-03-05 11:13:45>> last call for agent 1019 before customer call
100030     0              1033        4         844       0         5      2022-03-05 11:11:18  2022-03-05 11:25:26>> last call for agent 1033 before customer call
100031     0              1026        13        717       0         5      2022-03-05 11:15:15  2022-03-05 11:27:25
100032     0              1028        3         404       0         5      2022-03-05 11:19:16  2022-03-05 11:26:03
100033     0              1022        12        883       0         5      2022-03-05 11:21:15  2022-03-05 11:36:10
100034     0              1022        7         832       0         5      2022-03-05 11:21:15  2022-03-05 11:35:14
100035     0              1011        9         699       0         5      2022-03-05 11:24:53  2022-03-05 11:36:41

                                    2022-03-05 11:26:13 2022-03-05 11:28:42>> customer call should be here
                                    
100036     0              1028        2         893       0         5      2022-03-05 11:29:21  2022-03-05 11:44:16
100037     0              1026        12        820       0         5      2022-03-05 11:29:45  2022-03-05 11:43:37
100038     0              1019        12        835       0         5      2022-03-05 11:31:08  2022-03-05 11:45:15
100039     0              1033        3         213       0         5      2022-03-05 11:35:20  2022-03-05 11:38:56
100040     0              1022        8         670       0         5      2022-03-05 11:40:31  2022-03-05 11:51:49
100041     0              1011        15        149       0         5      2022-03-05 11:41:33  2022-03-05 11:44:17
100042     0              1022        15        109       0         5      2022-03-05 11:57:29  2022-03-05 11:59:33
100043     0              1019        11        639       0         5      2022-03-05 11:58:41  2022-03-05 12:09:31
100044     0              1033        11        513       0         5      2022-03-05 11:59:44  2022-03-05 12:08:28
```

Below is a snippet from the script I'm using. This part should return the ID of these two available agents:

```
DECLARE @Counter int = 1;

WHILE (@Counter < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ResourcePool1) + 1)
BEGIN
    SET @ID = (SELECT AgentID 
               FROM @ResourcePool1 
               WHERE RecordID = @Counter);

    PRINT 'AgentID = ' + CAST(@ID as nvarchar);
        
    IF((SELECT COUNT(SessionID) 
        FROM AgentConnectionDetail AS ACD 
        WHERE ResourceID = @ID
          AND ((@CustomerCallStartTime > ACD.StartDateTime 
                AND ACD.EndDateTime > @CustomerCallEndTime)
               OR
               (ACD.StartDateTime > @CustomerCallStartTime 
                AND @CustomerCallEndTime > ACD.EndDateTime)
               OR
               ((@CustomerCallStartTime > ACD.StartDateTime) 
                AND (@CustomerCallStartTime < ACD.EndDateTime) 
                AND (@CustomerCallEndTime > ACD.EndDateTime))
               OR
               ((ACD.StartDateTime > @CustomerCallStartTime) 
                AND (@CustomerCallEndTime > ACD.StartDateTime) 
                AND (ACD.EndDateTime > @CustomerCallEndTime)) )) >= 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'True';
        SET @var2 = (SELECT COUNT(SessionID) 
                     FROM AgentConnectionDetail AS ACD 
                     WHERE ResourceID = @ID
                       AND ((@CustomerCallStartTime > ACD.StartDateTime 
                            AND ACD.EndDateTime > @CustomerCallEndTime)
                            OR
                            (ACD.StartDateTime > @CustomerCallStartTime 
                             AND @CustomerCallEndTime > ACD.EndDateTime)
                            OR
                            ((@CustomerCallStartTime > ACD.StartDateTime) 
                             AND (@CustomerCallStartTime < ACD.EndDateTime) 
                             AND (@CustomerCallEndTime > ACD.EndDateTime))
                            OR
                            (ACD.StartDateTime > @CustomerCallStartTime 
                             AND ACD.EndDateTime > @CustomerCallEndTime)));
            
        PRINT 'Count = ' + CAST(@var2 as nvarchar)
        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;

        PRINT 'Counter = ' + CAST(@Counter as nvarchar);
    END
    ELSE 
        GOTO FINISH;
END

IF (@Counter > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ResourcePool1))    
BEGIN
    SET @ID = 0;
    PRINT 'reached to go to FINISH';

    GOTO FINISH;
END
```

Just to clarify, `AgentConnectionDetail` (ACD) is the name of the table above and `@ResourcePool1` is table variable to group those agents who receives calls from same call queue (queue ID is 5 in this case as seen in the table)

Comment: (Edit) You left out some important information A) Please post a sample of the rows in @ResourcePool1 during the sample time period and B) What's the actual values of the variables `@CustomerCallStartTime` = 2022-03-05 11:26:13  and `@CustomerCallEndTime` = 2022-03-05 11:28:42?

Answer (score 1):

More question than comment due to length.  Your approach might be more complex than it needs to be.  You can edit your existing post with more details and clarification.

If your queue of available agents is in some other table, and this AgentConnectionDetail table holds a list of ALL calls that are COMPLETED, you might consider another approach.

If you have a call coming in at ex: 2022-03-05 11:26:13 2022-03-05 11:28:42 per your example.  It appears your call center entries are relatively short, such as 3-15 minutes.  The query below does a check for all calls within the last hour associated with all in your resource pool.  It gets a count of all calls covered, AND the most recent END OF CALL per resource pool agent.  The final order is based on that most recent end of call so whoever finished their call first floats to the top of the list.

Now, if you have some other table that identifies who MAY be on another call assignment, you just need to exclude them.  Otherwise, you can apply a top 1 to get whoever is the next agent who should be assigned the next call.

```
select
        -- for each resouce ID, get the latest time the call completed
        ACD.ResourceID,
        max( ACD.EndDateTime ) LastCallCompleted,
        count(*) CallsCovered
    from
        AgentConnectionDetail ACD
            -- only query for those still in the random pool
            JOIN @ResourcePool1 rp
                on ACD.ResourceID = rp.AgentID
    where
        -- subtract 1 hour from the current time to see only recent without
        -- having to query days worth of entries
        ACD.StartDateTime > DateAdd( hour, -1, getdate() )
    group by
        ACD.ResourceID
    order by
        -- by ordering by whoever had the OLDEST FINISHED call time
        -- would in essence be the next agent who should be assigned the next incoming call.
        max( ACD.EndDateTime )
```

Comment: I like that approach. Provides a nice summary of recent activity

Answer (score 0):

The current date logic looks overly complex. I think it could be greatly simplified by searching for Agents that were NOT currently a call during the @CallStart and @CallEnd time in question.

```
DECLARE @CallStart DATETIME = '2022-03-05 11:26:13' 
        , @CallEnd DATETIME = '2022-03-05 11:28:42'
SELECT *
FROM   ResourcePool1 rp
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   AgentConnectionDetail cd
      WHERE  @CallStart <= cd.EndDateTime
      AND    @CallEnd >= cd.StartDateTime
      AND    cd.ResourceId = rp.AgentId
)
```

**Results:** *See note below about Agent 1028*

```
RecordID | CSQID | AgentID
-------: | ----: | ------:
       2 |     5 |    1019
       5 |     5 |    1028
       6 |     5 |    1033
```

> i see that agents with ID 1019 and 1033 were available

I'm not sure if you're applying any other filters, but technically Agent 1028 seems to be available as well, as their previous call end time is `11:26:03.000` and the next was not until `2022-03-05 11:29:21.000`

> ```
> SessionId | ResourceId | StartDateTime           | EndDateTime            
> --------: | ---------: | :---------------------- | :----------------------
>    100028 |       1028 | 2022-03-05 11:04:35.000 | 2022-03-05 11:10:12.000
>    100032 |       1028 | 2022-03-05 11:19:16.000 | 2022-03-05 11:26:03.000
>    100036 |       1028 | 2022-03-05 11:29:21.000 | 2022-03-05 11:44:16.000
> ```